# Intersection of polyhedral sets

Tags: convex-analysis, linear-programming

can you please help me solve this problem?

I have two polyhedral sets defined as $P_{1} = \{x| Ax \le b\}$, $P_{2} = \{x| Fx \le g\}$. I have to find if $P_{1} \cap P_{2} \neq \emptyset$. It can be done by solving LP (linear programming) task where minimization function is zero ( min $0^Tx$ ).

My job is to write that LP task. Can you help me with that please?
I hope you will understand my problem because my English is not great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve the following LP:
$$
\min \; 0
$$
subject to
$$
Ax \le b \\
Fx \le g
$$
Any (feasible) solution to this problem is a proof that $P_1 \cap P_1 \neq \emptyset$.

Comment: thank you very much